# Understanding iteration

Tags: python

I have just started learning python basics. Going through python basics, I am stuck in this iteration algorithm and I don't have any idea how it works. It is very simple I know but as a new programmer, I don't have a hobby of writing code daily.

Here is the Code

```
for i in inputlist:
    if i > outputlist[-1]:
        outputlist.append(i)

return outputlist
```

What is output list is actually doing what is the meaning of -1 there

Comment: For each element of the list, it compares it to the last element added to outputlist. If its greater, it adds it to output list. So it essentially drop-sorts the inputlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is traversing the `inputlist` elements one by one and if the current element `i` in `inputlist` is greater than the last element in `outputlist`, then `i` will be appended to output list.

`outputlist` will be an increasing subsequence of `inputlist`.

I assume the code can be as such:

```
def f(inputlist):
    outputlist = []

    if inputlist:
        outputlist.append(inputlist[0])

    for i in inputlist:
        if i > outputlist[-1]:
            outputlist.append(i)

    return outputlist
```

The syntax `outputlist[-1]` gets the last element of `outputlist`. In most other languages it'll be equivalent to `outputlist[len(outputlist) - 1]` (considering 0-based list indexing).

As rightly pointed out in the comments, `outputlist` cannot be empty in the beginning otherwise we'll get `IndexError`.

Comment: `IndexError:`  output list is empty when you index the last element.

Comment: why It will show Indexerror

Comment: I would argue that appending a zero is misleading and incorrect. It will cause negative values in inputlist to be disregarded, and will always have a zero regardless of whether inputlist contains zero.

Comment: @ayushbhambore If you try to index an empty list, you get `IndexError` in Python. And in my previous edit, the `outputlist` was initially empty and I was indexing it with `outputlist[-1]`.